# Вставить строку, если такой ещё нет.

Tags: mysql

Почем выдаёт ошибку?

```
INSERT INTO post_votes (POST_ID, USER_ID, TYPE) 
VALUES (12,32,'+') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT USER_ID, POST_ID
WHERE ((USER_ID=32)AND(POST_ID=12)))
```

ВЫдаёт ошибку: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT USER_ID, POST_ID WHERE ((USER_ID=32)AND(POST_ID=12)))' at line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что вы выполняете [INSERT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) с условием.

Для решения вашей задачи есть несколько способов:

1. Поставить уникальный ключ на (USER_ID, POST_ID)
2. Проверять на стороне используемого языка программирования
3. Использовать конструкцию

[INSERT ... SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html)

```
INSERT INTO post_votes (POST_ID, USER_ID, TYPE)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 12, 32, '+') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT USER_ID, POST_ID FROM post_votes WHERE POST_ID = 12 AND USER_ID = 32
) LIMIT 1;
```